# Hibernate не видит данные в базе

Tags: java, hibernate

**UPD - вопрос решил.**

Сломал всю голову...

Ситуация следующая, если очень в кратце

1. Добавляю машины в базу
2. Запрашиваю пару машин из базы
3. Все ок, хибернейт их видит

Останавливаю приложение

1. Смотрю на те машины которые есть в базе
2. пытаюсь их запросить
3. Хибернейт их не видит
4. Добавляю новую машину
5. Хибернейт её видит, но не видит машины добавленные в предыдущий запуск приложения.

В чем может быть проблема? =\

Создание сессии:

```
private static SessionFactory createSessionFactory() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().addAnnotatedClass(DailyReport.class).addAnnotatedClass(Car.class).configure();
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
        builder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = builder.build();
        return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    }
```

конфиг

```
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_example</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">*****</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <mapping class="model.DailyReport"/>
    <mapping class="model.Car"/>
```

Comment: Какая база? Если Н2 - то она в памяти и соответственно существует только пока запущено приложение.

Comment: .... база MySQL. Но я похоже сказал выше, что данные в базе есть... Значит можно сделать вывод что это не "временная база"

Comment: Значит приведите код, как происходит запрос к базе.

Comment: Если решили вопрос, то, пожалуйста, напишите ответ, чтобы помочь другим

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в следующем, у меня был метод *покупки машины*

```
public Car buyCar(String brand, String model, String licensePlate) {
    Car car = null;
    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Car where brand = :brand" +
                " and model = :model and licensePlate = :licensePlate");
        query.setParameter("brand", brand);
        query.setParameter("model", model);
        query.setParameter("licensePlate", licensePlate);
        car = (Car) query.getSingleResult();
        transaction.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (session != null) {
            try {
                session.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return car;
}
```

и все было хорошо, до тех пор пока не совершалась перезагрузка приложения в целом. И старые данные становились не видны.
Проблему конкретно в моей случае решило добавление одного метода **.setMaxResults(1)**

В строку

```
        car = (Car) query.setMaxResults(1).getSingleResult();
```

Пока я до конца не понял почему это так сработало. И почему хибер переставал видеть старые записи в базе. Хотя они там присутствовали. **Если у кого-то есть идеи почему так происходило - велкам...**

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте следующий вариант файла `HibernateUtil`, где написана вами `SessionFactory`:

```java
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static StandardServiceRegistry registry;
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            try {
                // Create registry. По умолчанию берет данные из hibernate.cfg.xml
                registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build();

                // Create MetadataSources
                MetadataSources sources = new MetadataSources(registry);

                // Create Metadata
                Metadata metadata = sources.getMetadataBuilder().build();

                // Create SessionFactory
                sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                if (registry != null) {
                    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
                }
            }
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    // Не обязательно
    public static void shutdown() {
        if (registry != null) {
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
        }
    }
}
```